# How do I print individual sentences from a Python list of sentences?

Tags: python, list, printing

The code below prints the individual characters within the list instead of printing the sentences themselves. How can I rectify this error?

```
# Modify this function to return a list of strings as defined above
def list_benefits():
    things = ["More organized code", "More readable code", "Easier code reuse", "Allowing programmers to share and connect code together"]
    for k in things:
        return k
# Modify this function to concatenate to each benefit - " is a benefit of functions!"
def build_sentence(benefit):
    return "%s is a benefit of functions!" % benefit

def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    list_of_benefits = list_benefits()
    for benefit in list_of_benefits:
        print(build_sentence(benefit))

name_the_benefits_of_functions()
```

This is my output:

```
M is a benefit of functions!
o is a benefit of functions!
r is a benefit of functions!
e is a benefit of functions!
  is a benefit of functions!
o is a benefit of functions!
r is a benefit of functions!
g is a benefit of functions!
a is a benefit of functions!
n is a benefit of functions!
i is a benefit of functions!
z is a benefit of functions!
e is a benefit of functions!
d is a benefit of functions!
  is a benefit of functions!
c is a benefit of functions!
o is a benefit of functions!
d is a benefit of functions!
e is a benefit of functions!
>>>
```

Comment: Your `list_benefits()` will return only one (the first) item from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your function `list_benefits()` will return all individual sentences instead of the whole list, and later you even apply list on the individual sentences. Then modify `list_benefits()` to return the whole list

```
# Modify this function to return a list of strings as defined above
def list_benefits():
    things = ["More organized code", "More readable code", "Easier code reuse", "Allowing programmers to share and connect code together"]
    return things
# Modify this function to concatenate to each benefit - " is a benefit of functions!"
def build_sentence(benefit):
    return "%s is a benefit of functions!" % benefit

def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    list_of_benefits = list_benefits()
    for benefit in list_of_benefits:
        print(build_sentence(benefit))

name_the_benefits_of_functions()
```